# Changed Host: Simple connection test script throws HY000/2002

Tags: php, server, localhost, hosting, host

I have this simple connection script that I've used for a while and it's worked well for me.

```
<?php
# mysql db constants DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASS, DB_NAME
const DB_HOST = 'xxx.xx.xxx.xx';
const DB_USER = 'myuser';
const DB_PASS = 'mypass';
const DB_NAME = 'myname';

$conn = new mysqli_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASS, DB_NAME);

if ($conn->connect_errno) {
    die("Connection failed: " .$conn->connect_errno. ": " .$conn->connect_error);
} else {
    echo "Connected successfully";
}
?>
```

I test my connection from localhost (or the host we used to have) and what I get on the page is:

> Connected successfully

Recently we changed our host (**where the script lives**) to **domain.com** and when I run the same test script from above on this host I get

> Warning: mysqli_connect(): (HY000/2002): Connection refused in
>   /hermes/bosnaweb04a/b2140/.../newdbtest.php
>   on line 8
>
> Connected successfully

Line 8 from above is:

```
$conn = mysqli_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASS);
```

The main problem is that while it tells me "connected successfully", I think the warning is trying to inform me about what's screwing up the overall site because essentially nothing really works (like a login functionality), though it works when on my localhost environment or the old host we had.

---

*Note:* *I updated the code to reflect the best practice/version of what I've tried. Jay Blanchard's answer so far as helped to assist with these updates though the problem at hand is so far unresolved.*

Comment: has the ip of your database server changed?

Comment: @RoshanBhumbra I changed the IP accordingly

Comment: And I guess you successfully recreated the user accounts with the same credentials?

Comment: `mysqli_connect()` requires 4 arguments to connect. You are using only three.

Comment: Always is going to echo "connected successfully " you have to put this echo in else condition

Comment: @RafaelShkembi sorry, typo

Comment: @8protons i do it all the time :D

Comment: @JayBlanchard Any idea what it still connects and makes successful inserts on my localhost but not the new domain?

Comment: Put also your database in mysqli_connect as @JayBlanchard suggested

Answer (score 3):

`mysqli_connect()` requires four arguments to connect successfully:

```
const DB_HOST = 'xxx.xx.xxx.xx';
const DB_USER = 'myuser';
const DB_PASS = 'mypass';
const DB_NAME = 'myname';

$conn = mysqli_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASS, DB_NAME) or die(mysqli_error($conn));
```

I would also use the `or die()` (procedural) method of exiting in the event you don't get a connection. In my opinion, you should stick with either procedural or OOP methods, for cleanliness (not that you can't mix, it just makes it harder to follow).

In addition, check the MySQL port number being used on your local machine as well as the remote. This could easily explain the differences between the servers.

Comment: Any idea what it still connects and makes successful inserts on my localhost but not the new domain?

Comment: It could be your environment on your local machine, but I would have to see that in action. I have never seen a successful connection without 4 arguments.

Comment: Maybe you include a file that has the database configuration?

Comment: Changing to `new mysqli( ... );` worked. I had that before actually and it just being weird at the time lol. It's all still connecting but still getting this 2002 error :/

Comment: Changing to `new mysqli()` made what work? Your `if` condition? The OOP method still requires 4 arguments.

Comment: Sorry, I mean to say making the changes you requested work on my localhost, previous host, but still doesn't fix the new host throwing 2002 at me.

Comment: What port is MySQL using locally? Remotely? Typically it is 3306.

Comment: @JayBlanchard The port is 3306 like you said. I have a MySQL DB via phpmyadmin. When I run the **php** script on my machine or on my local company server, my script connects just fine to the DB. But if I run that very same script on the new host we got (domain.com), this is where I get the error.

Comment: Is the MySQL database running on your new host?

Comment: @JayBlanchard Yeah. I've changed the DB_HOST IP accordingly :[

Comment: What about the port on the new host?

Comment: dreamhost, where my DB lives, has the standard 3306 port set as default. It just won't accepted the darn connection from the website hosted by domain.com

Comment: So, wait - you're trying to perform a cross-domain database connection? You will need to check whether Dreamhost's MySQL server is set to accept connections from other hosts (see the bind-address directive in your my.cnf or my.ini), and that the username you connect with is set to be able to connect from external domains.